# How can I fill text in between CSS grid gaps?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-row-1">...</div>
  <div class="grid-row-2">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Is there a way to automatically fill text like `---AND---`, or `---OR---` in between those grid rows?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is considered elegant, but it will work:

```
<style>
    .grid-container > .and::after{
        content: "---AND---";
    }
    .grid-container > .or::after{
        content: "---OR---";
    }
</style> 

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-row-1 and">...</div>
  <div class="grid-row-2 or">...</div>
  ...
  <div class="grid-row-100">...</div>
</div>
```

or you can do this:

```
<style>
    .grid-container > div::after{
        content: "---AND---";
    }
    .grid-container > div:last-child::after{
        content: "" !important;
    }

</style> 

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-row-1">...</div>
  <div class="grid-row-2">...</div>
  ...
  <div class="grid-row-100">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can use .grid-container > div:last-child instead of .grid-container > .end